# Condensed categories vs categories (co)tensored with condensed sets

Tags: ct.category-theory, enriched-category-theory, condensed-mathematics, internal-categories

I am not sure how to solve set-theoretic issues properly, so let me first ignore them.

There are two notions, probably closely related:

1. Condensed categories, i.e. condensed objects in the category of (large, but I am not sure how to deal with size issues — see Update below) categories. This might be equivalent to internal categories in the category of condensed sets.
2. A category tensored and cotensored over the category of condensed sets.

I wonder how these two notions are related precisely, under some goodness assumptions (like presentability)? A priori, they are different: the (equivalence classes of) objects in the first notion form a condensed set, while they form a set in the second notion. One can also consider $\infty$-categorical analogues, and I do not expect that it is very different from the 1-categorical case, thus I will mainly discuss the 1-categorical case, and assume tacitly that everything works for $\infty$-categories.

It seems to me that the second notion is favored — all definitions that I know are out of the second notion. For example, the concept of analytic structures on a condensed ring $R$ is described by a subcategory of the category of $R$-modules, with properties characterized by tensor (to form the internal Hom) and cotensor over condensed sets, cf. [[Lectures on Analytic Geometry](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Analytic.pdf), Prop 12.20].

We remark that, given a condensed ring $R$, we can also associate with a condensed category: the functor maps a profinite set $S$ to the category of $\underline{\operatorname{Hom}}_{\operatorname{CondSet}}(S,R)$-modules.

---

**Update:** As Zhen Lin correctly differentiated in [the comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442876/condensed-categories-vs-categories-cotensored-with-condensed-sets#comment1143044_442876), I am more interested in condensed large categories "of mathematical objects". Since I am not sure how to solve the set-theoretic issues, I did not mention it. But here is a possible way: we consider the category of $\kappa$-condensed $\lambda$-presentable categories, and take (informally) the union over $\kappa$ and $\lambda$.

Comment: You could ask the same question about simplicial categories: are they literally simplicial objects in the category of categories, or simplicially-enriched categories? In practice it turns out that we don't really need the extra generality of having a simplicial set of objects. I imagine it's the same for condensed categories.

Comment: (Caveat: I am mainly thinking of "category theory in the large", which deals with large categories as a way of organising mathematical objects. There is also "category theory in the small", which deals with small categories for more ... exotic ... purposes. For instance, categories as homotopy types following Quillen, Thomason et al would be "category theory in the small".)

Comment: I think condensed categories appear in Lurie's paper *Ultracategories* in the form of stacks on $\mathcal{C}\mathrm{omp}\mathcal{H}\mathrm{aus}$. In fact, the 2-category of ultracategories embeds fully faithfully into the 2-category of condensed categories.

Comment: They also appear in the *Exodromy* story of Barwick--Glasman--Haine. The condensed structure of Galois category of a scheme is a crucial ingredient in the exodromy equivalence. (Up to set theory, pyknotic is condensed, right..?)

Comment: @BrianShin By "ignoring" set-theoretic issues, I mean I do not know how to deal with them correctly to formulate a very precise question, but I do care about them: the category in consideration, as Zhen Lin pointed out [above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442876/condensed-categories-vs-categories-cotensored-with-condensed-sets#comment1143044_442876), are large categories, while Galois categories are "condensed small diagram categories". I try to clarify it by updating the question.

Comment: @ZhenLin I heard that there are recent developments of internal (higher) categories in a topos. Maybe both the simplicial case and the condensed case belong to that. However, I am not technically equipped enough to understand that (e.g. internal presentability). Moreover, I am mainly interested in the case where the topos is "good" enough as in the condensed case, e.g. generated by compact projective objects, say.

Comment: The dichotomy is in fact already present in the "ordinary" category theory. Dealing with small and large categories has distinctly different flavors, and the leading examples are quite different in nature. And, in fact there is also a third level, when you do not even insist on homs to be small. A model of the elementary theory of categories is just a class of arrows between objects, with certain properties, there are no requirements on the subclass of arrows with fixed endpoints.

Comment: One important fact is, I think, that the associated stack of a small category need not be small(able).